# Overload resolution ambiguity when using Java enum in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I am using the java enum io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.avro.AvroCompatibilityLevel in Kotlin code

```
public enum AvroCompatibilityLevel {
   NONE("NONE", AvroCompatibilityChecker.NO_OP_CHECKER),
   // ...

   public final String name;
   public final AvroCompatibilityChecker compatibilityChecker;

   // ...
```

In Kotlin I'd like to make use of

`AvroCompatibilityLevel.NONE.name`

but this leads to an

```
Overload resolution ambiguity. All these functions match:

public final val name: String? // coming from the field name

public final val name: String // coming from enum
```

Can anyone point out how to overcome this issue?

Comment: If you have access to the original Java code you should rename `name` to something else or create an accessor (e.g., `getName()`). If you can't modify the original Java code then I guess there's not much you can do other to fallback to writing a Java wrapper

Comment: I do not have access to the code , but I guess there needs to be another way to overcome this issue then to duplicate the class

Comment: As a workaround for this certain case you can call `toString()` on `AvroCompatibilityLevel` instances instead of using `name`. According to the [source code](https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/blob/master/client/src/main/java/io/confluent/kafka/schemaregistry/avro/AvroCompatibilityLevel.java) it will give the same results.

Answer (score 1):

You can write an extension property to extract the value of the member field "name" like this:

```
import kotlin.reflect.full.memberProperties

private val innerNameCache = mutableMapOf<AvroCompatibilityLevel, String>()
val AvroCompatibilityLevel.innerName: String
    get() = innerNameCache.getOrPut(this) {
        AvroCompatibilityLevel::class.memberProperties.filter { it.name == "name" }[0].get(this) as String
    }

fun main() {
    println(AvroCompatibilityLevel.NONE.innerName)
}
```